# Write TestCases using PageFactory (Selenium-WebDriver). Advantages?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, test-framework

Is it a good practice to go the PageFactory way when writing testcases in Selenium2? If yes why?

To be frank I have never used them when writing test-cases and have not missed it either. But I would to know what are the advantages of using PageFactory over not using it.

Comment: Please edit the question to make it better. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my point of view the advantages are on the one hand, all the ids and xpaths at only one place in code, on the other hand the abstraction layer between the implementation an the test itself.

This will allow non- programmers to test the websites what's useful for me, because some people know exactly what the workflows are and which functionality is the most important but are not part of the development teams or engineers at all.

Last but not least, the [PageFactory](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) term is quite useful.

Based on these reasons we decided to switch from over 500 Selenium 1 testcases to Selenium 2 with PageObjects. And try to compensate the effort of creating POs, which will surely exceed the effort for std test executions, by increased maintainability, usability and scalability

Comment: is this the only reason (all the ids and xpaths at only one place?) you could have done the same thing without using pagefactory and create a class and define all your ids, xpaths as global constants?

Comment: This is the first sentence, yes. If you keep on reading, you'll find some more advantages...